# Why does C need a null zero as a string terminator while Java doesn't?

Tags: java, c

I noticed that when I created a character arrays to hold strings in C I always needed to add a null zero at the end as a terminator. For example:

```
char Month[10];
Month[0] = 'M';
Month[1] = 'a';
Month[2] = 'r';
Month[3] = 'c';
Month[4] = 'h';
Month[5] = '\0';
```

Here I need to add`Month[5] = '\0'`to make the char array display the right result. If I ignore the null zero it will give result `March_\377`. But in Java I would still get `March` without adding the null zero. I want to know how do C and Java deal with this situation differently?

Comment: In Java, all strings are objects which are immutable. In C, you can sort-of recreate the same by making a pointer to `char` point to a string literal. But, still, your question seems too broad as every language has its own similarities and differences.

Comment: @Edyyy The answer you know yourself: they indeed deal with this situation differently.:)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow well, it's not just an arbitrary choice. Having a String object with a length attribute avoids having to iterate through the whole string to find the '\0'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in C there is no type `string`, there is only a pointer to a `char`. When in C you need a string, you need to know how many characters are in the string, or have an indicator to see that you have reached the end of the string.

Traditionally there are two approaches to this requirements. In the C world the convention is to terminate the string with the `\0` character. In the PASCAL world the convention is to use another variable to store the length of the string.

Java uses the PASCAL convention and stores the length of the string in another variable as the content of the string.

Both approaches have their merits. In the Java/PASCAL world, it is easy to know the length of the strings and a string can contain the \0 character. In C you can reuse the same character array for tail substrings etc.

Comment: Well, there are `char` arrays in C. These are not pointers to `char`.

Comment: Yes, the strings can indeed be stored in `char` arrays (like in the question), but for the C sting logic it is not really important whether the `*char` points to an array, to the middle of an array or to any other memory containing `char`s.

Answer (score 8):

In Java, we have a class named `String` which has a method called `length()`.

In C, you need to have a `\0` at the end of your string so you could know where your string ends. But in Java, this problem handled with the method`length()`.

Comment: As of Java 8, it seems that this variable has been removed. `length()` simply `return backedCharArray.length;` (in fact it also disappears in some versions of Java 7)

Comment: Sorry for the edit mess; that was mostly because I was confused by `count` as well, and `length()` is usually the way of getting a string's length in Java.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's not in the doc, since it's a private state that does not need to be exposed. But you can find it in the source code (at least it was true before java 7) (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String)

Comment: @Joey No regards to Alexis's comment you were right, it seems that they dont use `count` in `length()` anymore.

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't have strings as an actual data type and the convention is just that character arrays ending in a null character can be used as strings. That's what you get when you use string literals in the language and that's what you have to recreate when you don't use them.

The underlying issue is that C wanted to save memory on its string representation by not storing a length (Pascal stored the string length in the first byte for example), thus the length has to follow somehow from the data, in this case by ending the data with `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, a string is mostly an abstraction, where you are not supposed to care about the internal representation. You have methods that perform operations on it and that allow you to obtain information about the string.

In C, however, this is quite the opposite. You want to know and care a string's  internal structure, in order to avoid segmentation violations.

Moreover, in C the null-terminated sequence of chars that composes a string occupies a contiguous set of memory locations. Most string functions (strcmp, strcat, and so on) expect that you will have a null terminated string to know where the end of the string is. So, in case you don't have the null character in the end, then the string function can run off the end of the string.

Comment: Well, the internal representation is a sequence of UTF-16 code units. That's fairly well-known and -documented.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I was not referring to that. I was simply stating that you do not need to care about the internal representation. So I will replace "know" with "care" in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a board question, we have to point out two important things here:

1) First thing to confirm is, C as being a basic language and having low abstraction, it doesn't have string as a datatype. In C, string is just a collection of chars. So we need some thing to specifies where the string ends, for that we use \0 null terminator (which tells the library that, this is where the string ends)

**So, why \0 null terminator:** Null termination happens to be the way chosen for C, for string literals and the standard library functions that deal with strings. Obliviously, It's convenient because the null character is not really used for anything else. It's not printable neither it's a control character nor it has any behavior defined to it (like moving the cursor in some particular way, for example \t)

Also, according to the ISO C standard, section 7.1.1, defines a string this way:

```
 A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.
```

2) Java is a matured language, what i mean is, it is high level language than C. In Java, we can define the string as:

```
A String is defined to be a fixed length sequence of char values. All possible char values (from 0 to 65535) may be used in a String. There is no "distinguished" value that means that the string ends.
```

**So, how they track string ending?**  String class provides a method called length to know the number of characters in the string.

So, you can clearly see from the language implementation prescriptive that, C requires Null termination for string because, they are nothing but a sequence of characters and need a special character to determine where this sequence ends, while, java strings are implemented as classes (& objects).

**Extra Notes:** I know this is not asked, but i am specifying, If you're reading the Java string's data in C code via JNI, then we use JNI functions like GetStringChars() or GetStringUTFChars(). Neither of these functions are not documented as returning null-terminated data, we should use GetStringLength() to determine its length. Likewise with GetStringUTFChars(), you must use GetStringUTF8Length() to determine its length in modified UTF-8 format.